# Python design: OOP

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to do something along these lines:

```
class A:

    def __init__( self, x=None, y=None ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class B( A ):

     def do_something_in_Bs_context( self ):
         print "In B"

class C( A ):

    def do_something_in_Cs_context( self ):
        print "In C"


a = A(1,2)
b = B.do_something_in_Bs_context( a )
c = C.do_something_in_Cs_context( a )
```

As expected this code will generate this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method do_something_in_Bs_context() must be called with B instance as first argument (got A instance instead)
```

The underlying reason for this design is that A is a container of data ( say a table ) and B and C are a set of operations on A. Both B and C operate on the same data but are conceptually a distinct set of operations that can be performed on the same data. I could club all the operations in B and C inside A, but I want to create the separation in concepts. (As an example, on a table, I can perform different sets of operations which may be grouped into say Calculus or Trignometry. So A:Table, B: Calculus, C:Trignometry)

This reminded me of the Model-View-Controller paradigm with a slight twist.

I came up with the following solutions:

1. B and C are implemented as conceptually different classes (a
   View/Controller) that maintain a reference to an instance of A and
   operate on that instance.
2. Since B and C just group together
   methods on A, create modules with functions that operate on an
   instance of A.

I don't like either of these solutions much (2 slightly better than 1), but then I'm not sure if there is a  better/cleaner/more pythonic way to solve this problem is. Any pointers?

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of showing us the TypeError was, so I ignored it in my answer.

Comment: 1 & 2 seem perfectly idiomatic. Don't create a class if you just want to group a few functions together.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I understand the question:  `B` and `C` are collections of functions that consume data of type `A`.  What you want to do is group the functions logically.

I'd suggest doing one of the following:

1. separate the functions into classes `B` and `C` that operate on `A`'s -- this is a HAS-A relationship.  The functions/methods could be static, if that's what you need
2. separate the functions into modules `B` and `C`, creating top-level function definitions

I think inheritance would be a bad solution to this problem.  I don't think there's an IS-A relationship.

Comment: Agree, though I think that modules with functions is more Pythonic than static methods.

Answer (score 1):

Move state in an additional class and make an instance of it an attribute of A:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__( self, x=None, y=None ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class A(object):
    def __init__( self, state=None ):
        self.state = state

class B( A ):
    def __init__( self, state=None ):
        super(B, self).__init__(state)

    def do_something_in_Bs_context( self ):
        print self.state.x

class C( A ):
    def __init__( self, state=None ):
        super(C, self).__init__(state)

    def do_something_in_Cs_context( self ):
        print self.state.y

s = State(1, 2)
b = B(s)
c = C(s)
b.do_something_in_Bs_context()
c.do_something_in_Cs_context()
```